# Cant load random array text and having errors with document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

I am always getting errors when I do this, Im trying to get a random number to be chosen then have text from an array get selected from that random number and display one thing of the array after every page reload. I have a paragraph tag that has the ID of "one".

```
var meth = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

var contentText = ["Shrimp","Rhino","Dog"];
if (meth === 1) {
   document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = contentText[0];
} else if (meth === 2) {
   document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = contentText[1];
} else if (meth === 3) {
   document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = contentText[2];
} else {
   document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = "Loaded incorrectly";
}
```

Comment: "I am always getting errors when I do this" — What errors?

Comment: "I have a paragraph tag that has the ID of "one"." —There's a button in the question editor's tool bar that opens a live demo editor. Use it. Include the HTML needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have provided an answer that should work but I have no idea what error actually occurred, please provide that information next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes to the code that could improve it :3

**Essential:** `container.innerHTML = selection[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]`

I wouldn't use an `if` statement for such a thing.. here a `switch case` would make more sense. **BUT** don't use a `switch` or `if` statement to convert an integer to an integer.

**DEMO:**

```js
// Settings up constants
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const getRdmEle_btn = document.getElementById("getRdmEle_btn");
const selection = ["Shrimp","Rhino","Dog"];

// Call function for the first time
getRandomElement();

// Add event listener for demonstration
getRdmEle_btn.addEventListener("click", getRandomElement);

// Filling the container
function getRandomElement() {
 container.innerHTML = selection[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]
}
```

```html
<p id="container"></p>
<button id="getRdmEle_btn">Get random Element</button>
```

Comment: xD No problem ... everyone makes mistakes :)

Comment: This makes sense, I didn't know you couldn't get items from arrays with if statements

Comment: WAAITT xD of course you can get Elements from array with an if statement. But why would you do `if(n == 1) array[1]` and not `array[n]`

Comment: I'm trying to do a project and I thought about doing that, but... I figured it would hurt me in the long run

Comment: Just ask another question, format it correct, deliver all the info and tell us what you tried (and google first). Then people will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var meth = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
    var contentText = ["Shrimp","Rhino","Dog"];
    var element = document.getElementById("one");
    if(element != null) {
        if (meth === 1) {
            element.innerHTML = contentText[0];
        }
        else if (meth === 2) {
            element.innerHTML = contentText[1];
        }
        else if (meth === 3) {
            element.innerHTML = contentText[2];
        }
        else {
            element.innerHTML = "Loaded incorrectly";
        }
    }
});
```